# Holding Refresh Button

Tags: asp.net, iis

When user holds refresh button , url is sent to the server as many times as it makes my woker process hang 
is there is any feature in the iis to handle the user request ( when the same request is sent is short interval of time )

Answer (score 1):

Not in IIS itself. It is designed to answer requests as they come. The options available are more related for looking for DDOS attacks.

You still want to be able to handle this kind of traffic generally, whether it comes from a single user or not. If the process hangs, look for code that is not destroying objects when done with them. Disposable objects that don't have their Disposable methods called before they are nulled. SqlConnection or other database connection that is left open.

You have to be careful because it is possible that legitimate requests could be blocked by using software and settings, especially when a number of computers are using a site behind a network router as they can all appear as a single IP address, the address of the modem for that network (as in the case of small businesses that tend to use residential routers and ISP setups).

Comment: thanks for your answer ,but please is there any quick resolve for this problem my application is now live and my client is complaining about this problem

Comment: There really isn't a quick fix, especially if it's an architecture issue. I haven't seen many cases where uses hold the refresh button, and most users have no idea there even is a refresh button. Does the client know that users are hitting refresh? Have you tried things like enabling caching? Are you ensuring that any scripts or css you are referencing are minimized and bundled in order to avoid additional requests? Each of these requests is one more resource the server has to fetch and respond to.